# Prometheus Query : Joining 2 metrics in Grafana

Tags: prometheus

Metric 1: `custom_closed_orders_total{store="5222"}` results in:

```
host1,host2,host3,host4
```

Metric 2: `host_offline:health_check_container:sum{store="5222"}` results in:

```
host1,host2,host3,host4,host5,host6
```

I would like to have a query which shows the following result:

```
host5, host6
```

The best that I could do is:

```
(count(custom_closed_orders_total{store="5222"} offset 7d) by (host)) 
- on(lane) group_left(host) 
count(host_offline:health_check_container:sum{store="5222"} offset 7d) by (host)
```

Can someone please help me how to get the expected results by modifying the above query?

Comment: Can some one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you are looking for how to get the values of one metric that is not present on the second metric (or vice-versa). If so, you can use the `unless` (complement) operator [as the docs says](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators):

> vector1 unless vector2 results in a vector consisting of the elements of vector1 for which there are no elements in vector2 with exactly matching label sets. All matching elements in both vectors are dropped.

You can do something like this:

```
host_offline:health_check_container:sum{store="5222"} 
unless 
custom_closed_orders_total{store="5222"}
```

Be aware that the order of the metrics used before or after the `unless` function matters. As a demo example [check this](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=alertmanager_notifications_failed_total%20%0Aunless%20%0Aalertmanager_notifications_total%7Bintegration%3D%7E%22opsgenie%7Cemail%22%7D&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=alertmanager_notifications_total%7Bintegration%3D%7E%22opsgenie%7Cemail%22%7D%0Aunless%20%0Aalertmanager_notifications_failed_total%20&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h).